# Proof for calculating market elasticity of demand

Tags: demand

I have heard that the market elasticity of demand for a good is the weighted sum of the individual price elasticities of demand for that good but cannot find any information about it online. Could someone please supply a proof that shows this?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a population of individuals $\{1,\ldots, n\}$ with individual demands $x_i(p)$ (depending on the price of the good). Market demand is then defined by:
$$
X(p) = x_1(p) + \ldots + x_n(p) = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i(p).
$$
Taking the derivative on both sides gives:
$$
\frac{\partial X}{\partial p} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial p}.
$$
Now multiply both sides by $p$ and divide by $X$ to obtain:
$$
\frac{p}{X} \frac{\partial X}{\partial p} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{x_i}{X} \frac{p}{x_i} \frac{\partial x_i}{p}.
$$
So:
$$
E^X_p = \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i e^{x_i}_p.
$$
Where $E^X_p$ is the price elasticity of the market demand. $e^{x_i}_p$ is the price elasticity of individual $i$'s demand and $w_i = \frac{x_i}{X}$ is the share of $i$'s demand in overall market demand.